# Loop through a 3d vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix

I've a 3D vector holding images in Matlab, its 480x640x1400. I want to loop through the 1400 images. For I want to get the median of the first 10 images (from 1-->10) and save it as a one 480x640 image then get the images from 2-->11 and get the median and save it as another image and so on (3-->12)....
So for example:
images is the 3D vector holding images with size 480x640x1400
images2 is the required 3D vector holding the median of the images with size 480x640x1400.
This is the script I'm using:

```
l=dir('*.mat');
filenames={l.name}';
nfiles=length(filenames)
idx=1;
strtidx=1;
endidx=nfiles;
step=1;
waitbar(0);
for i=strtidx:step:1
    tmp = load(filenames{i},'images');
    idx=1;
    for j=strtidx:step:1000
        for k=j:step:j+9
            tmp2(k)=tmp(:,:,k);
        end
        mm=median(tmp2,3);
        images2(j)=mm;
    end
    save(filenames{i}, 'images2', '-append');
    waitbar(i/nfiles);
    close all;
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a matrix with the dimensions you described called `Images`. Firstly it could be a normal matrix of images, or a cell matrix. Are these colour images? Secondly you only have 1400 images, not 1401, Matlab indexes from 1 not from 0.

If it is a normal array of single channel images (i.e. greyscale) then you want this:

```
for imageNumber = 1:size(Images,3)-9 %loop along the third dimension
    NewImages(:, :, imageNumber) = findMedian(Images(:,:,imageNumber:imageNumber + 9)) %findMedian is your own function that you must write that outputs the median of 10 images as a 480 x 640 matrix.
end
```

Comment: what is the reason of tje "-9" here for imageNumber = 1:size(Images,3)-9 ?

Comment: It's because you wanted to look at 10 image at a time. You'll notice in the next like I consider `imageNumber:imageNumber + 9`, so the reason the loop only goes to `size(Images,3)-9` is so that later when I add 9 it doesn't go past the end of the matrix. Try it without it and you should see an out of bounds error